# how to create deep list of string with key and value

Tags: java, list, hashmap

there is a way to create list in java (of string) like the following.

String ,

the string in the brackets should be like key val.

I saw someting like this

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> csvData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

but instead the hash map I want to put string so the structure will look like
for example.

```
person<name,ben>
      <lastname,tagds>
      <age,30>  
      ....
emp  <firstname,jhon>
     <name,bbb>
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>
```

?
This way person, emp, etc. will be the first `hashMap` keys and `<name,ben>,<lastname,tagds>`  will be in the internal HashMap.

Comment: @baraky- how you would define it?

Comment: This is the definition of the map. What else do you need?